# Program on Debian8.3 appears different than on Fedora18

Tags: debian, fedora, libraries, qt

I've made a couple of programs (Let's call them *ProgressBar* and *LabelsAndInfo*) with Qt4.8 and C++ for my enterprise's HW.  It runs on a **Fedora 18** and it works fine. Now, a mate is trying to run all our software on a **Debian 8.3** and here start the problems:

- **LabelsAndInfo:** is 1 single window with some labels with text, Line edits, buttons, etc. The colour of the text (this text is red) in labels is made with simple CSS ("`color: red`") while the colour of the background is made with  a CSS3 property ("`background: linear-gradient(direction, color1, color2, ...);`").

**The problem:** While on Fedora my background is a gradient that goes from white to light blue, which is the behaviour I want... on Debian it is empty(the same .exe), and has  the default colour of Qt windows which is something between grey and white.

That makes me think that maybe the problem has something to do with the CSS version and maybe the Debian needs any library.. **BUT** there is more...

- **ProgressBar:** This program is equal to LabelsAndInfo but instead of labels and line edits, it has a progressbar an a label. also label text is made with css. Both programs have been compiled equal but in ProgressBar, the Background colour is shown on Debian as it is on Fedora (with the gradient white-blue) which makes me think that Css version is not the problem so... I'm really lost thinking what may be happening right now...

Thank you so much.

Comment: Give it a try with up-to-date Fedora. Fedora 18 is EOL.

Comment: @Jakuje sorry can't change both versions... It has to be with those versions of OS

Comment: What version of Qt do you have installed in each machine?

Comment: @Roflo its the same in both OS and the one I use: 4.8

Comment: did you recompile your programs on the debian system, or did you just copy the binaries?  library versions etc will be very different between 3+ year old Fedora and the current Debian stable release.

Comment: @cas The exe of my program is the same. About the libraries.. they are diferent as every Os has their own Qt libraries.